# Firebase hosting deploy to other site

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

how to deploy to other firebase hosting sites defined within the same project.
I created multiple firebase hosting "sites".
The command

```
firebase deploy
```

however always deploys to the first one.
How can I specify that the static files get deployed to another "site" (and domain).

Thanks

Comment: Google blog on this: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/one-project-multiple-sites-plus-boost.html

Answer (score 48):

You have to add the other sites as [deploy targets](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites). If you have a second site named `awesome-site-d3426`:

```
$ firebase target:apply hosting awesome-app awesome-site-d3426
```

You'll likely have to do the same thing for the primary site.

Then tell Firebase what to deploy to which targets in `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "awesome-site",
      "public": "awesome-site/dist"
    },
    {
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

You can then deploy all the sites at once(`firebase deploy`) or a specific site:

```
$ firebase deploy --only hosting:awesome-site
```

Comment: Great answer. Had a really hard time finding how to do this on the firebase cli documentation. Thanks Abraham!

Comment: Funny thing is that I only mads a small edit to the Hosting part of my firebase.json ie `"site": "mySitesName"` . And even weirder is it never worked when I specified `"public" : "mySitesName/dist"` or `"public" : "public"`.... it only deployed when i wrote `"public" : "."` .. seems like a fluke but the site is live and working

Comment: seems the targets are superfluous.  I just added the site id to firebase.json as the "target" and I was able to deploy to it

Answer (score 8):

To deploy to another site created in same firebase project.
Update your firebase.json file as folow

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "site":"<site-name>",
    "public": ...,
    "ignore": [
      ...
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```